# Get torrent content hash

Tags: bittorrent

some know a tool to get hash of the content of a torrent file?

suppose have a b.torrent with files c and d, some way to get the hash of c and d (or some data to can validate the files i don't necessary have the files).

i already try with the tools of this post but there we only can get the name..
[Is there a tool to view a torrent file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31486/is-there-a-tool-to-view-a-torrent-file)

The only thing, i need can use the data so ideally an terminal output (not a program only saying the file is correct or not).

Thx.

Answer (score 3):

a `.torrent` file stores a hash list of all the pieces that make up the whole torrent , but not a hash list for individual files.

Wikipedia :[Torrent file Structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torrent_file#File_structure)