# How to move the torrent data around on a per-tracker basis?

Tags: files, bittorrent

Note that I'm looking for a fully **client-agnostic** method for managing torrent data — I don't want to be tied to a specific program and I'm confident that the task can be achieved with general Unix tools.

To illustrate, I've loads of completed torrents from [archive.org](https://archive.org/details/americana) and [Kiwix](https://wiki.kiwix.org/wiki/Content_in_all_languages) and would for organization purposes benefit if the data was copied (or rather, symlinked) to dedicated directories in (e.g.) `~/torrents`, from the client's download folder:

```
/home/user/torrents/
├── archive.org
└── kiwix
```

A torrent file contains the torrents directory structure and the trackers used (if any). [The .torrent files can be inspected](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31486/is-there-a-tool-to-view-a-torrent-file) with `transmission-show` for instance.

In essence:

1. read the torrent files stored in the client's session directory (`~/.config/transmission-daemon/` for transmission)
2. identify where each torrent's data is stored
3. copy or symlink the data to a tracker-specific directory (see the output of the `tree` command above) from the torrent client's download folder (usually `~/Downloads`).